# chart.js cnnot see the shape of data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

[image]

it works in localhost but after i do publish the application  that's the result i find
this is the code i tried with

```
        var firstChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
                        type: 'pie',
                        data: {
                            labels: ["Açık  " + words[0] + "%", "Kapanan  " + words[1] + "%"],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: "Population (millions)",
                                backgroundColor: ["#e74c3c", "#3498db"],
                                data: [words[0], words[1]]
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            showAllTooltips: true,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Bakiye'
                            },

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: chart is displaying?

Comment: post full code to understand better